# Where to implement Async task in slow to load custom ArrayAdapter within a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, listview, asynchronous

I have a Dialog fragment which contains a layout with a ListView in it. I use an Alert Builder within my custom `DialogFragment.onCreateDialog()`. Before returning the dialog to the invoking fragment I create my adapter and set the listView's adapter to it. This is very slow, my custom adapter has a lot of work to do. I have tried using async tasks to set the adapter after adding a default adapter but it still laggs out. I assumed that the default adapter would load quickly then when the async finished it would update the listView.

Custom `DialogFragment onCreateDialog()`:

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        currentGoals = MhaCacheManager.getInstance().getUserGoals();
        if(currentGoals!=null)
        {
            Log.d("GoalsEdit", "Added onCreateDialog here");
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Goal edit")
                    .setMessage("Edit your goals")
                    .setView(rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_goal_edit_dialog, null))
                    .setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            listener.onEditValue(currentGoals);
                            Log.d("GoalsEdit", "Accept goals edit!");
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //AddFriendDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
                        }
                    });
            Dialog result = builder.create();

            result.show();
            result.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
            result.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

            goalsList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

            String[] test = {"Loading Data"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, test);
            goalsList.setAdapter( myAdapter);

            new DialogLoaderAsync(getActivity(),goalsList,this).execute(); // The asymc task that sets the adapter in the passed listView!

            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Async task `DialogLoaderAsync`:

```
public class DialogLoaderAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    private Context context;

    private ProgressDialog mDialogProgress;
    private ListView lView;
    private GoalsArrayAdapter.OnDialogUpdated mParent;
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;

    public interface OnArrayAdapterLoaded
    {
        public void onArrayAdapterLoaded();
    }
    public OnArrayAdapterLoaded listener;

    public DialogLoaderAsync(Context context, ListView lView,GoalsArrayAdapter.OnDialogUpdated mParent)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.lView=lView;
        this.mParent=mParent;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        ArrayList<MhaCacheManager.UserGoals> currentGoals = MhaCacheManager.getInstance().getUserGoals();
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new GoalsArrayAdapter(context, currentGoals, mParent);
        lView.setAdapter(myAdapter); // Really time consuming.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void param)
    {
        lView.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

It is as if when adding anything to an active view it hangs the UI thread? Where can I do the work?

Comment: can you put adapter code also?

Comment: Are there too many elements to display?

Comment: `Where to implement Async task` - nowhere. Don't use `AsyncTask`, because it's too easy to shoot yourself in the leg. Specifically, do not touch `listView` from outside of main thread. Regarding performance issues - do profiling, see what exactly is "slow".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think problem is custom adapter. It seems like you are getting data on main thread here

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    currentGoals = MhaCacheManager.getInstance().getUserGoals();
    if(currentGoals!=null)
    ...
    ...
```

Why I am saying this: You are using same method `currentGoals = MhaCacheManager.getInstance().getUserGoals();` in your Async task too. Seems like you are using same method in main thread too. try removing above mentioned code from `onCreateDialog` and it should work fine.

Comment: Yeah I see that repeated method now, must have got left in while I experimented with different solutions. Thanks for the heads up. As for it lagging the UI thread it simply pulls an arrayList with no more than 8 objects in it. I will remove it and see, after my holiday :)